# Android) In this case, is voice output possible on the dialog?

Tags: android

I'd like to print out the 'laptop' in the dialog by voice. Is Android Studio enough?
Thank you in advance.

[image]

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.listview_detection, 
R.id.detectionText, listItems);
list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.detectionResult);
list.setAdapter(adapter);

//Item click 
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    System.out.println(listItems.get(position));

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CameraActivity.this);
    String msg = labelSubTextResult(listItems.get(position));
    builder.setTitle("Detection Result").setMessage(msg);

    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();

    alertDialog.show();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Android SDK is enough. Simply get the `TextToSpeech` instance and use it when ready.

```
TextToSpeech tts =new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new 
    TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
         @Override
         public void onInit(int status) {
            if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
               t1.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
            }
         }
    });

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
        String toSpeak = ed1.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toSpeak,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        tts .speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
     }
  });
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It was very helpful.